# Flutter Multi Language App: MaterialApp won't rebuild when locale is changed with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, locale, riverpod, gorouter, riverpod-generator

I am currently working on a flutter app, using GoRouter and Riverpod (with riverpod generator in some parts). I managed to implement a multi-language feature which is linked to the device settings with flutter_localizations.
I would like now to allow the user to change the language in the app via a settings page, but somehow I can't figure out how to do that, and I can't find much documentation about implementing this in a Riverpod/GoRouter environment. The right behavior would be that the app checks if the user stored a language code, if there is one the app is built on the corresponding locale, and if not, it would try to build with the one from the device settings, and if that one isn't implemented, by default in english.

Here is the code:

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  Environment environment = const StagingEnvironment();
  Widget app = await initializeApp(environment);
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: app));
}
```

**app.dart**

```
Future<Widget> initializeApp(Environment environment) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  return AppWidget(
    environment: environment,
  );
}

class AppWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Environment environment;
  const AppWidget({Key? key, required this.environment}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<AppWidget> createState() => _AppWidgetState();
}

class _AppWidgetState extends ConsumerState<AppWidget> {
  late AuthRepository authRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    authRepository = AuthRepository();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialAppWidget(
      environment: widget.environment,
      currentLocale:
          ref.watch(languageControllerProvider.notifier).currentLocale,
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Environment environment;
  final Locale? currentLocale;

  const MaterialAppWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.environment, this.currentLocale})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<MaterialAppWidget> createState() => _MaterialAppWidgetState();
}

class _MaterialAppWidgetState extends ConsumerState<MaterialAppWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainTheme = ref.watch(appThemeProvider);
    final GoRouter goRouter = ref.watch(appRouterProvider).router;
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      locale: widget.currentLocale,
      routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
      routeInformationProvider: goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      theme: mainTheme.initMaterialThemeData,
      builder: (context, child) {
        Widget body = Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: child,
        );
        if (isNotBlank(widget.environment.bannerText)) {
          body = Banner(
            message: widget.environment.bannerText!,
            location: BannerLocation.bottomEnd,
            child: body,
          );
        }
        return body;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**language_controller.dart**

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class LanguageController extends _$LanguageController {
  Locale? _locale;

  Locale? get currentLocale => _locale;
  @override
  Locale build() {
    return _locale = Locale('fr');
  }

  setLocale(String languageCode) {
    _locale = Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: languageCode);
    return _locale;
  }
}
```

**settings.dart**

```
class Settings extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Settings( {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<Settings> createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends ConsumerState<Settings> {
  Language? _language;
  bool _loading = false;
  bool _isChanged = false;
  Locale? currentLocale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    setState(() {
      currentLocale = locale;
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    currentLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    _language = languages.firstWhere(
      (language) => language.locale.languageCode == currentLocale!.languageCode,
      orElse: () => languages.first, 
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    final appTheme = AppTheme.of(context, ref);
    final userNotifier = ref.watch(userControllerProvider.notifier);
    final languageNotifier = ref.watch(languageControllerProvider.notifier);
    Future showLanguages() {
      return showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
            ),
          ),
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      l10n.selectLanguage,
                      style: appTheme.textHeadline3,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: languages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 30,
                                width: 40,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                child: Flag.fromString(
                                  languages[index].locale.countryCode!,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: appTheme.marginSmall),
                              Text(languages[index].name),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _language = languages[index];
                            });
                             languageNotifier.setLocale(_language!.languageCode);
                            userNotifier
                                .savelanguage(_language!.languageCode);
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const Divider();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: appTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
        title: Text(
          l10n.settingsTitle,
          style: appTheme.textHeadline1,
        ),
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (_isChanged) {
                showConfirmModal(context, l10n.confirmQuitProfileTitle, ref,
                    confirmLabel: l10n.quitWithoutSave,
                    confirmAsyncCallback: () => context.pop());
              } else {
                context.pop();
              }
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: appTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
            )),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${l10n.language}: ',
                    style: appTheme.textHeadline3Light,
                  ),
                ),
                if (_language != null)
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => showLanguages(),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 30,
                            width: 40,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                            child: Flag.fromString(
                              _language!.locale.countryCode!,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: appTheme.colorGreyDark,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            _language!.name,
                            style: appTheme.textHeadline3Light,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the settings page, when clicking on the selected language, a bottom sheet opens to select a new one. But the MaterialApp widget doesn't rebuild with the new locale, even though there is a ref.watch on the locale argument. The change applies though when I hot reload.
Any advice please?